# 受ける Usage (Translation)

Tags: translation, usage

I have the following to translate for class.

```
漢字クイズは
習った漢字を全部暗記しなくてもいいですが
例文を読んだ後で
受ければ
いい点が取れるようです。
```

So far I have the following.

```
As for the kanji quiz
it is okay if you don't memorize all of the kanji that you have learned but
after reading the sample sentences
if you ???
it seems like you can get a good score.
```

I have only seen `受ける` translations as recieve/catch/take/have etc. Nothing seems to really make sense for this sentence.

Can anyone think of a good translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes perfect sense.

「クイズ」 is like a small "test".  "To take a test" = 「テストを[受]{う}ける」.  「受ける」 is by far the most natural and often-used verb for this.

例文を読んだ後で
受ければ
いい点が取れるようです means:

> "It seems like we/you could make a good score if we/you took (the quiz) after reading the example sentences"

Comment: Hrm. I guess I was expecting it to be more like "if you look it up" or something. Our kanji quizzes are take home and they are essentially just sentences. So I was expecting "look at the sentence and then look up the kanji". Ty

Comment: I guess the "but" is a bit weird. At least for English. A "because" would seem more natural. "You don't have to memorize all of them because it seems like you can get a good score if..."