# Usage of 受ける in 日本の大学を受けたいです。

Tags: nuances

A book I am studying has 日本の大学を受けたいです。translated as "I want to apply to a Japanese university."

Finding it a little confusing to nail down what sense of 受ける is being used here.

Comment: Related: [Meaning of the verb 受ける in the phrase 試験を受ける](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41721/43676), [受ける Usage (Translation)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15733/43676)

Comment: I read that before posting. Though still doesn't make sense to me, wouldn't that read "receive a Japanese university?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 受ける basically means "to take (an exam, a job interview, an audition, etc.)". We say 試験を受ける, テストを受ける, 面接を受ける, オーディションを受ける and so on.

Since applying to a university/company/job almost always involves some kind of test/interview, we can just say 京都大学を受ける, トヨタを受ける, シンデレラ(役)を受ける, and so on, too. Always saying ～の入学試験を, ～の入社試験を or ～役のオーディションを is bothersome, so 受ける in such cases automatically means taking the corresponding test without explicitly saying it. "To apply to ～" is usually a natural translation, but you cannot use 受ける if there is no exam. For example, you cannot say ボランティアを受ける. The more direct translation of "to apply to " is ～に出願する, but this is a rather stiff kango verb that is not very common in informal speech.

This is a fairly common derivative usage of 受ける, although it was not listed in monolingual dictionaries I checked.

(By the way, does "to take Kyoto University" make sense in English, too? At least DeepL recognizes this usage...)

Comment: ‘By the way, does "to take Kyoto University" make sense in English, too?’ < Nope. As for a similar analogy (namely, focusing on the fact that there is a test of sorts involved) I guess “tried for” might fit… but while it’s acceptable I feel it’s not *that* common in the context of university, and has more to do with it being a challenge than literally a test.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thank you for the input! So DeepL is not always perfect :D

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the difficulty lies in (not) understanding how to get into Japanese universities in general.

Unlike (at least most, I believe) US universities, if you want to attend a Japanese  University X, you need to do the following.

1. Apply to University X. This usually means sending the application form + high school records. There is no 'statement of purpose' kind of thing (I don't know how exactly US college admission works, so ignore this comment if it is not common either.) Recommendation is usually a formality.
2. Take the 大学入学共通テスト (formerly センター試験) if X is a public university (as opposed to private uni). This is something like SAT/<strike>GCSE</strike>A-levels in US/UK. This is usually for screening, you have only to reach a minimum score (set by the university X).
3. Take the second test which is prepared by the university X. You need to score top r% to pass it, where r depends on the capacity of the university X.

There are *many* variations, but the normal procedure is as above.

What is (probably) particular to Japanese (or many Asian) university admission is step 3: Each university prepares its own paper test, which is more or less proportionally difficult along with the prestige of the university. And this step 3 is by far the most important (high school GPA does not matter really, again I don't know how things are in other countries). Thus *being admitted to a university X* is largely synonymous to *passing the test prepared by the uni X*. Hence 大学を受ける means (その)大学の試験を受ける=*take the test prepared by the university* or *apply to the university*, 大学に受かる means *admitted to the university*.

Comment: Irrelevant correction: The exams used primarily for university admission in the UK are A-levels (taken at 18) rather than GCSEs (taken at 16).

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for the correction. Although totally off-topic, what are decided based on GCSE then? Just curious.

Comment: Until recently (I think it's changed now) kids could leave school when they were 16. So GCSEs were a way to test their ability before they left the school system for the world of work. The results are also used as entrance requirements by some sixth form colleges (where A levels are studied).